# GTK list: import text

Tags: list, gtk

I want add a list in my C program...I know how build a list with GTK+, add string at opened program, etc...but it's different when you want "maintain" the content of list. I thought to save the content in a .txt file (I've two column, 1st contains a string type and 2nd contains int type), but when I open the program, how can I import .txt file's content in the list?
I thought to separate string type and int type with a space, load .txt file's content in a vector, insert string type in a vector, int type in another vector and assign the values of vector with string type to 1st column and values of vector with int type to 2nd column.
But I see this as a bad idea.
Some good idea?

Comment: I want a good idea to send data from a .txt file for example, in a list...every data in the appropriate column (there are different data type). I obviously use GtkTreeView and GtkListStore.
I think using a .txt file isn't the best idea, so I want another (good) idea.
I'm thinking of using SQLite, but "lighter" solutions are accepted.

Answer (score 0):

When you're reading records from the .txt file, you should insert the values in a GtkListStore, then [GtkTreeView](http://library.gnome.org/devel/gtkmm-tutorial/unstable/chapter-treeview.html) is used to [display the result](http://scentric.net/tutorial/) from the [GtkListStore](http://library.gnome.org/devel/gtkmm-tutorial/unstable/chapter-treeview.html).

Comment: But how can I share values in the appropriate columns with a good method?
I'm thinking of using SQLite.